# How to use sidebar and main content in express handlebars with a layout

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have a express handlebar application with **main.hbs** as the layout file.

```
//main.hbs
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
     {{> header}}
     {{{body}}}

     <script src='/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
     <script src='/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When i click a link let's say "settings" in dashboard page then it redirects to settings page where i have sidebar and main content page.
This page also uses **main.hbs** as layout.

```
//settings.hbs
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="active"><a href="/settings/account">Account<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/settings/view">Views</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sites</a></li>
        </ul>         
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="active">Settings</li>
        </ol>
        <div id="settingsContainer">  
            //Content should be rendered here just like the {{{body}}}                
        </div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

So how can i able to render the desired content inside the "settingsContainer".

As per my understanding in layout file {{{body}}} is used as a placeholder for where the main content should be rendered.

But this is a different page. Is there a way i can render the content based on the link clicked from sidebar.

Any help and pointer will be much appreciated!

Comment: _What_ content should be rendered in `#settingsContainer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know much about handlebars but you can achieve the same with bootstrap tabs.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
        <div class="tabbable">
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="active"><a href="#account" data-toggle="tab">Account<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#views" data-toggle="tab">Views</a></li>                  
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="active">Settings</li>
        </ol>
        <hr>
        <div id="settingsContainer">
            <div class="tabbable">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="account">
                        //render partial for account
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="views">
                        //render partial for views
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps